# Different RecurringJobs executing at the same time

Tags: hangfire

I'm trying to execute a process to update my database, but the problem is that I set different RecurringJobs for it at different hours.

Today when I checked hangfire status, since yesterday that I instanced hangfire, I found the job should execute yesterday and the one task for today, both executed 30 minutes ago at the same time, and this has created duplicates in the database.

Can you help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is one of concurrency, you can solve it by running hangfire single threaded. Simply configure the number of hangfire worker threads on startup:

```
var server = new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
                                         {
                                             WorkerCount = 1
                                         });
```

This will force hangfire to process queued jobs sequentially.

Alternatively, if you have the Pro version of hangfire you can control order using [batch chaining](https://www.hangfire.io/pro/#chaining-batches).

> I don't know if a worker can be considered as a thread.

Within a hangfire worker, single threaded code will be run by exactly one thread

Comment: Perfect I will try it. It will help if I use a monitor?

Comment: @JoseMMartin - what is a monitor?

Comment: A lock I mean, to avoid the concurrency in different threads. I don't know if a worker can be considered as a thread.

Comment: @JoseMMartin - within a worker, single threaded code will be run by exactly one thread.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a concurrency issue as has been suggested.  It's not completely clear what you are trying to do but I'm assuming you want the job to run at 7, 12:45, and 17:30 and had issues because both the 7am and 17:30 job ran at the same time (7am).

Based on the created time it looks like you created these around 14:30. That means the 17:30 job should have ran but didn't until the next morning around 7am. My best guess is this was hosted in IIS and the site app pool was recycled.
 This would cause any recurring jobs that were supposed to run to be delayed until the app pool / site was started again (which I assume was around 7am).

Check out these documents on how to ensure your site is always running: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

If it's not an IIS issue something must have caused the BackgroundJobServer to stop monitoring the database for jobs until ~7:00am (server shutdown, error, etc).